# What is the the fastest instance/networking/way to transfer S3 bucket from one account to another?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am Copying an S3 bucket from one AWS account to another. I did some research and am now using an instance using m5n.2xlarge with enhanced networking enabled for the transfer machine. I have seen speeds between 5 and 10 MiB/s.

What would you recommend to use or do to get a faster transfer of the S3 bucket?

Comment: Why not use the [Bucket Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) feature provided by AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that replication is a much faster method. Here is a link to a very easy tutorial on how to set it up.

https://medium.com/@chrisjerry9618/s3-cross-region-replication-2e20f2dc86e0

Also note that if you want to copy/replicate existing objects then you need to open an AWS ticket :
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/replicating-existing-objects-between-s3-buckets/